# Outputting an XML document in Swift after appending an element into it

Tags: ios, swift, xml, struct, xml-parsing

Is there a way in Swift that I can add an element to an XML document after passing it through a function?

For example, if I pass in the text of `<original>` into a function, can I append it after into the XML file and save it as a new XML document?

##### input XML

```xml
<original>item-id-01</original>
```

##### custom function

```swift
func doThings(_ string: String) -> String { ... }
doThings("item-id-01")
```

##### output XML

```xml
<original>item-id-01</original>
<destination>output from custom function</destination>
```

I'm trying to parse an XML file **without using a library** but all the tutorials I've seen only seem to only show how to append one element into an array, and display that into the UI.

That is, most examples:

```xml
<book>                        -->    struct Book {
  <title>My book</title>      -->      var title: String
  <author>Dr. ABC</author>    -->      var author: String
</book>                       -->    }
```

The `XMLParser` and `XMLParserDelegate` will search for the `elementName == "book"` and then append that to an array of `var books: [Book]`. This seems to be the popular use of XML parsing since it was the way to get data before JSON was the standard.

However, I want to be able to pass in my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="1.2">
  <file file-location="Local/Folder/file-a.txt" original="192.168.0.1" destination="192.168.0.2">
    <header>
      <tool id="com.apple.TextEdit" name="TextEdit" version="14.0" build="123ABC"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <item id="item-id-01" xml:space="preserve">
        <original>item-id-01</original>
        <note>Notes: no notes recorded</note>
      </item>
    </body>
  </file>
  <file file-location="Local/Folder/file-b.txt" original="192.168.10.1" destination="192.168.10.2">
    <header>
      <tool id="com.apple.TextEdit" name="TextEdit" version="14.0" build="123ABC"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <item id="item-id-02" xml:space="preserve">
        <original>item-id-02</original>
        <note>Notes: no notes recorded</note>
      </item>
    </body>
  </file>
</data>
```

Get all the `<original>` elements, pass them into the `doThings()` function, and have an XML document that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data version="1.2">
  <file file-location="Local/Folder/file-a.txt" original="192.168.0.1" destination="192.168.0.2">
    <header>
      <tool id="com.apple.TextEdit" name="TextEdit" version="14.0" build="123ABC"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <item id="item-id-01" xml:space="preserve">
        <original>item-id-01</original>
        <destination>output from custom function</destination> // <--- custom text
        <note>Notes: no notes recorded</note>
      </item>
    </body>
  </file>
  <file file-location="Local/Folder/file-b.txt" original="192.168.10.1" destination="192.168.10.2">
    <header>
      <tool id="com.apple.TextEdit" name="TextEdit" version="14.0" build="123ABC"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <item id="item-id-02" xml:space="preserve">
        <original>item-id-02</original>
        <destination>output from custom function</destination> // <--- custom text
        <note>Notes: no notes recorded</note>
      </item>
    </body>
  </file>
</data>
```

When I use the XMLParserDelegate, I'm able to extract all the `<original>` text into an array of `Item()` models:

```swift
struct Item {
  var original: String
  var destination: String?
  var note: String
}
```

Then `compactMap` the `Item.original` into a String array, so I can pass it to my function:

```swift
let items: [Item] = []
let original: [String] = []

init() {
  items = XMLParser.getDataFrom(url: ...)
  orignal = items.compactMap({ $0.original })
}


func doThings(_ string: [String]) -> [String] { ... }

let output = doThings(original)
```

But how would I inject into the original XML document and essentially "Save As.." into a new file?

##### Things I tried

- adding the entire XML document into their own struct models and looping through all of them to rebuild

  - this didn't work for me as I couldn't get the attributes into the model and output it as it originally was
  - eg. `<file file-location="Local/Folder/file-a.txt" original="192.168.0.1" destination="192.168.0.2">` into

  ```swift
  struct File {
    var header: Header
    var body: Body
    var atributes: [String : String]
  }
  ```
- convert the XML to a string, find all the `</original>` and replace it with `</original><destination>loopValue[index]</destination>`
- this didn't work because if there already was a `<destination>` in the original XML document, then I would end up with `</original><destination>loopValue[index]</destination><destination>.. original document data</destination>`

---

Am I not using the correct API or is there a good way to achieve this outcome?

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use XMLDocument, it's a bit cumbersome but certainly the right tool for the job.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson XMLDocument looks perfect with the `addChild` and `insertChild` but I couldn't get it to work with the above example XML file. I'm clearly doing something wrong but I couldn't find anything helpful on how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary version of how to read and update the xml using XMLDocument. Note that we are only dealing with classes here so everything is by reference which makes the update part a bit simpler.

```
let document = try! XMLDocument(xmlString: xmlString) //Change this to a suitable init

let nodes = try! document.nodes(forXPath: "/data/file/body/item")
for node in nodes {
    if var item = node as? XMLElement {
        let element = XMLNode.element(withName: "destination", stringValue: "some string value") as! XMLNode
        item.addChild(element)
    }
}
```

Then use `document.xmlData` or `document.xmlString` to extract and a save the modified xml

*And you shouldn't use `try!` everywhere as I have done here* :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on

> without using a library

the only option you are left is `libxml2`. `libxml2` is a low level `C` Api, so not really much fun in using it.

For `macOs` there would be the alternative of `XMLDocument` but for `ios` you are stuck with `XMLParser`.

Comment: Sorry! I typed so much i forgot to mention I’m only doing macOS. So XMLParser

Comment: @markb I know. Hence my comment on beeing stuck. Just out of curriosity, why not using a third party library? Most of those are just a wrapper around `libxml2`.

Comment: Having third-party code in a project can become inconvenient or worse due to the library relying on specific versions of the language, certain versions of the OS, and maybe even other third-party libraries. I work with a team using Java for servlet development, and they have four different versions of a third-party library because they keep wanting the newest features but are unwilling to port the old code to the new version of the libraries. Getting all the right libraries working together on a new computer takes hours, if not days! That's why I would also want "without using a library."